# How can i exclude values of fields in a columngroup

Tags: reporting-services, sum, expression, iif

I am somewhat new at this whole SSRS topic but i'll try to make it as clear as possible.

I have a Report that looks something like this:

Value A | Value B | Value C | Value D | SUM
__________________5______2______7
__1000__5000______1______3______6

The sum in row 1 acts as it should. however row 2 counts the not-empty-fields of Value A and B. This is because i had to change the query in the stored procedure the Dataset draws its values from. Otherwise the Sum would show "6004"

I also tried to make another columngroup but that didn't work at all.

So i was wondering if there is a way to tell the Sum to subtract 1 if there is a Value in the columns "Value A" and "Value B"

I was able to find other posts with similar qestions but not quite what i was looking for and i wasn't able to make it work by trying some stuff.

I guess it would look somewhat like this:

=SUM(Fields!Typ.Value)-(IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!Typ.Value="Value A"),1,0))

Comment: Try `=SUM(Fields!Typ.Value) -
 (IIF(IsNothing(Fields!ValueA.Value) OR IsNothing(Fields!ValueB.Value),1,0))`

Comment: sadly this is not working. <br> error [BC30455] for the Parameter false part of public function IIf(Expression as Boolean, TruPart As Object, FalsePart as Object) As Object no Arguement was specified.